# How to return a list of maximum-nrow data frames?

Tags: r

Given the minimum example of data:

```
dfA <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","a"))
dfB <- data.frame(B=c("b","b"))
dfC <- data.frame(C=c("c","c","c"))
combineList <- list(dfA, dfB, dfC)
```

I would like to return to a list, one data frame per list element, the data frames with the maximum number of rows i.e., dfA as one list element and dfC as the second list element. It should ignore dfB as it has too few rows.

A further example:

```
dfA <- data.frame(c("a","a","a"))
dfB <- data.frame(c("b","b"))
dfC <- data.frame(c("c","c","c"))
dfD <- data.frame(c("d","d","d","d","d"))
combineList <- list(dfA, dfB, dfC, dfD)
```

I should only have a list of one element: dfD, as it has five elements.

I'm trying to avoid some arcane C style set of for loops with integer flags.

Comment: Did you meant `i1 <- sapply(combineList, nrow); combineList[i1 != min(i1)]`

Comment: Thanks all. I'll give each a go and see if it does what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use this:

```
ind <- sapply(combineList, nrow)
combineList[ind==max(ind)]
```

Comment: combineList? What package does that belong to?

Comment: @AnthonyNash - It's the name of your list.

Comment: *sigh*, sorry - very long day.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
combineList[which.max(sapply(combineList, nrow))]
```